# ~10 min web post from within airflow operators getting stuck/hanging

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

Airflow operators are getting stuck when they include a web post that takes ~10 minutes.

##### The following operators failed:

1. PythonOperator that includes code to send an http post request with the requests library.
2. Same as 1 but with a PythonVirtualenvOperator (Tested because of the second response on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980623/why-is-my-airflow-hanging-up-if-i-send-a-http-request-inside-a-task) thread)
3. PythonOperator that uses paramiko to ssh to the host and run a cURL to localhost.

##### The following operator worked:

4. BashOperator that makes a cURL call to the endpoint. However this approach is lacking in that it only supports one bash call. I could have airflow call a bash script, would would rather use python if possible.

###### Code for 1:

```
def post_using_requests():

    s=requests.session()
    s.auth = (<auth>)
    s.headers.update(<headers>)

    resp = None
    resp = s.post(<endpoint>, data = <data>)
    
    <----- Operator gets stuck here ----->
    
    # Check and process response

request_via_requests_lib_operator = PythonOperator(
    task_id = <task_id>
    , python_callable = post_using_requests)
```

###### Code for 2:

```
def post_using_requests_virtualenv():
    #Additional imports
    #Everything else the same as #1

request_via_requests_lib_virtualenv_operator = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id = <task_id>
    , python_callable = post_using_requests_virtualenv)
```

###### Code for 3:

```
def post_using_ssh():
    
    # get ssh_client
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    
    # credentials = <get_creds>
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(<credentials >)

    curl_command = "curl -X POST -sS --location <endpoint> --header <headers> --data <data>"

    _stdin, _stdout, _stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(curl_command) 

    <----- Operator gets stuck here ----->

    stderr_str = _stderr.read()
    stdout_str = _stdout.read()

request_via_ssh_operator = PythonOperator(
    task_id = <task_id>
    , python_callable = post_using_ssh)
```

###### Code for 4:

```
request_via_bash_cURL= BashOperator(
    task_id=<task_id>, 
    bash_command="""curl -X POST -sS --location <endpoint> --header <headers> --data <data>"""
)
```

##### What else I tried

The only similar issue I could find anywhere online was [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980623/why-is-my-airflow-hanging-up-if-i-send-a-http-request-inside-a-task). I did add

```
NO_PROXY="*"
```

to the file /aws-mwaa-local-runner/docker/config/.env.localrunner per the docker readme. However this did not fix the issue.

Airflow env spun up using this repo (branch 2.2.2): https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner/tree/v2.2.2

Comment: 2.2.2 is pretty old. I recommend upgrading to the latest version of Airflow (currently 2.7.1)

Comment: You mention stuck/hanging. Does the task fail after some time with any error? Or is it just hanging indefinitely (how long)?

Comment: Hanging indefinitely, no error is returned. At least 30minutes, I never let it run much longer than that.